# jQuery calculate price - sometimes "NaN" displayed

Tags: jquery

I have a form with imput field "pcs" which is number of pieces and two types of shipping, one is free and one is payed and I try to calculate the price on the go, but the script sometimes gets "NaN" or not recalculated, could anybody tell me, how to do that correctly? Thanks a lot, it's really appreciated.

```
jQuery("input").click(function (event) {

    var shipping = 0;

    var pcs = parseInt(jQuery('#kus').val());

    var kalkulace = function(shipping, pcs) {
        var price = 290;
        all = shipping + (price * pcs);
        jQuery("#price-total").val(all);
        return all;
    }

    var all = kalkulace(shipping, pcs);

    jQuery("input:checked").each(function () {
        if(!jQuery('#kus').val()) {
            var pcs = 0;
        }
        else {
            var pcs = parseInt(jQuery('#kus').val());
        }
        if (jQuery(this).attr("id") == "shipping1") {
            var shipping = 0;
            var all = kalkulace(shipping, pcs);
        }

        if (jQuery(this).attr("id") == "shipping2") {
            var shipping = 49;
            var all = kalkulace(shipping, pcs);
        }

    });

    jQuery('#price').text(all + ' Kč');

});
```

Comment: Seems like you could write some tests that would cover the different input cases so you could determine where the bug might be coming from

Comment: I would check for any values that might be translating into strings, such as "free" or "paid" or words of that nature. NaN simply means `not a number` so you probably have some other value getting thrown into the mix. Maybe make some tests using jQuery's .type() method.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking `if(!jQuery('#kus').val()) {` , you also need to check if a value can be converted into a number. You can use `$.isNumeric` expression to do that.

```
var pcs;
if(!jQuery('#kus').val() || !$.isNumeric(parseInt($("#kus").val())))
    pcs = 0;
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/j6um1sq2/9/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's already solved by input type, it can be either not set or numeric (1-100).